# How to store image data into SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have to store `System.Drawing.Image ImageObject` into the database. I have tried with `byte[]` like I do `ImageObject` convert to byte[] and than store to database but while storing the length of converted byte array is greater than max limit of binary data type of SQL.

How I store my data into database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the datatype to `varbinary(max)`. `binary` has a limit of 8000 bytes. Note: don't use the `image` datatype, unless you plan on using SQL Server 2005 forever (it is deprecated).